# Please don't do this?

Tags: discussion

[image]

The question's only twelve minutes old, it's the user's sort of *maiden* voyage here, and it's already got a negative three. That is not *welcoming*. It looks like the user might not be a native English speaker, but the question was written in English, and was readable. There's never really a good reason to take a question past, say, `-1` - why do it to a brand new user? You don't *have* to upvote it.

There were three comments - one from some user here, and the next two from this user saying polite things - *thanking* us.

It's just not nice. Please?

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/ and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252534#comment8259_252534

Comment: @Braiam - do you see any close votes in the picture? is there anything in that comment you linked to about voting to negative three *(which i rather think is kind or hilarious, and appreciated)*. come on... the guys got 1 xp and hes already devoured. that sucks.

Comment: @Braiam - [i took another picture](http://imgur.com/3HTo7jf)

Comment: Downvotes on questions don't cost rep, for a [very good reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90324/213575), and why close votes = downvotes? A question can be badly asked but being on topic.

Comment: @Braiam - im not saying *dont downvote* - i would ***never ever*** say that, im just saying *dont downvote the ten minute-old user to negative three within the first ten minutes*.

Comment: whoever upvoted the comment - thanks for not upvoting the question. the `-3` forever-mirror thing looks *cool*

Comment: dammit!​​​​​​​​

Comment: You should have linked the post, so that we can build our own judgement, but you eliminated every useful information (except the tags, but they don't help me, finding the post).

Comment: @userunknown - that was the point! i didnt want anybody pointing fingers or any such nonsense. you can say i made it up if you like, and you're welcome to disregard me as confused or stupid or any of those things because i dont offer anything here but my opinions - and youre equally entitled to those as well. but i asked *please*. anyway it wasnt intended as admonishment or a problem that required consideration or judgement - its just a request.

Comment: @mikeserv: I've seen similar suggestions about newbies posts, but examining the profile of the user showed, that he was new in that particular section, but a long time user of SO. So I can't see it that is the case here, too or not.

Comment: @userunknown - [well, ok fine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247641/can-i-run-ssh-tunnel-in-ram). it probably doesnt matter as much now as it did then - its not as fresh.  there are a few links to membership profiles of other network sites in the user's profile page, but all are 1 rep and the oldest is too months.

Comment: mikeserv, downvoted to make your wish come true. Happy :)

Answer (score 2):

I frankly think that regarding the score of your question as a true index of its reception by the community is a good mindset for users, but it's the result of *time spent using the site*.  It's not something that a first-time poster will necessarily do automatically.

Consider the inverse: would a first-time poster feel "welcomed" if he received three upvotes but no answers and no comments for a week?  (I think not.)

I believe "vote early, vote often" is the best approach, combined with a conditional "Add a helpful/welcoming comment if you can (assuming you can't just answer)."

---

The point is really: We welcome the new user, but only to the degree that they contribute and abide by the guidelines/rules.  We don't welcome everyone and anyone who wants to ask about anything without even reading the tour page or doing any research.  Otherwise we wouldn't have a community at all.  So we express through voting what questions we think should be validated and what should not be.  Applying a different standard to new users would be a version of "voting for the user instead of the content", which is frowned upon heavily.

Comment: i dont think its [all that frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/288824). and anyway, i never suggested the user not be downvoted - only that new users not be downvoted to -3 in 10 minutes time. -3 is unusual in the first place - pretty much *any* question ought to be given a half-hour to brew at least, i think. people edit stuff. and leaving a comment for a new user and later checking on it before clicking the button isn't all that bad an idea.